# Append nested JSON array with php

Tags: php, json, multidimensional-array

I have a nested json array in a file that looks like this:

```
{
"id": 12345679,
"gid": 6012,
"history": [
    {
        "date": "0000-00-00 00:00:00",
        "rank": 6
    }
]}
```

I am curious how I can read the json file and append the history array with php, then re-write the file named *data.json*.

This is what I've got thus far.

```
$json = file_get_contents('data.json');
$json = (array)json_decode($json);
$output = $json['history'][] = array(
    array('date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'rank' => 3),
    array('date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'rank' => 2),
    array('date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'rank' => 6)
);

  $data = json_encode(array_marge($json, $output));
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You're currently appending a block of three subarrays. What you want to do is appeand each individually:

```
$json['history'][] = array('date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'rank' => 3);
$json['history'][] = array('date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'rank' => 2);
$json['history'][] = array('date' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 'rank' => 6);
```

Then use that as `$output`.

Alternatively use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/array_merge) for adding your three-entry list onto the input `$json["history"]`. But don't merge the two arrays `$json` and `$output` like you tried last.